# Redirect web service

Tags: apache2

I have a web server that is running. There is a URL https://www.example.com/test/ (/var/www/html/test) How do I make https://test.example.com redirect to there?

I am using Apache 2.4 as my web daemon.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this depending on your Apache configuration and how the code that runs the site has been written. That said, the most basic method would be to set an `.htaccess` rule.

#### Assumptions:

1. The `test.example.com` has its own Apache configuration file (meaning that no other configurations will interfere with it)
2. Apache has been configured to follow `.htaccess` rules

   <sub>**Note:** If one or both of these assumptions is not met by the web server, then you can stop reading as everything below this disclaimer will be "wrong".</sub>

#### Setting Up the Redirect

1. Create or edit the `.htaccess` file:

   ```
   sudo vi /var/www/html/test/.htaccess
   ```

   <sub>**Note:** Feel free to use any text editor that you prefer.</sub>
2. Paste the following into the file. This should be the only content in the file:

   ```
   Options +MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
   Options -Indexes

   Redirect 301 / https://www.example.com/test/
   ```
3. Save the file

   There will be no need to restart or reload Apache. Test the redirect in a browser of your choice.

Comment: For your first point, do you mean adding a new virtual host using the Apache conf files?

Comment: I don't know if you need to add a config file. There are dozens of different ways a person might configure Apache. The assumptions section was put there to make it clear that if your configuration differs from the two conditions, additional work will be required on your part 